# winapi full screen leaves 3 tickles

Tags: c, winapi

here is a code I found here :
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/108400/How-to-Set-Win32-Application-to-Full-Screen-C
. I had a little problem with it. In part 1 it queries the window style and then in the second 2 part it defines styles that we will remove in part 3. then in part 4 leaves three butts on two sides and bottom. what can i do?

```
//move to full screen 
//1
DWORD dwStyle = ::GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
//2
DWORD dwRemove = WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
//3
DWORD dwNewStyle = dwStyle & ~dwRemove;
::SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, dwNewStyle);
//4
::SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES), ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES),SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raymond Chen gave the correct way to do this in his blog: [How do I switch a window between normal and fullscreen?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100412-00/?p=14353)：

Here is the sample that you can refer to :

```
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
WINDOWPLACEMENT g_wpPrev = { sizeof(g_wpPrev) };
void setFullWindow(HWND hwnd)
{
    DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    if (dwStyle & WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW) {
        MONITORINFO mi = { sizeof(mi) };
        if (GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &g_wpPrev) &&
            GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromWindow(hwnd,
                MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY), &mi)) {
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE,
                dwStyle & ~WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
            SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP,
                mi.rcMonitor.left, mi.rcMonitor.top,
                mi.rcMonitor.right - mi.rcMonitor.left,
                mi.rcMonitor.bottom - mi.rcMonitor.top,
                SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        }
    }
    else {
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE,
            dwStyle | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
        SetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &g_wpPrev);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER |
            SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
}
int WINAPI WinMain(_In_  HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_  LPSTR szCmdLine, _In_  int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    setFullWindow(hwnd);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```